# In my combo box i inserted multiple tables to show and i want to pass it to my data grid view and save it in db

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
 SQLiteConnection sqlcon = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = carRentalDB.db;Version = 3; New = False; Compress = True;");
        SQLiteCommand sqlcmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM Client", sqlcon);
        sqlcon.Open();
        SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            cbClient.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2] + " , " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1]);
        }
```

\this line of codes show the data from data grid view to my combo box

```
private void LoadData()
    {
        setConnection();
        sql_con.Open();
        sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
        string CommandText = "SELECT Rents.rental_id,Client.lName,Client.fName,Car.car_brand,Car.car_model,Car.plate_number,Rents.rental_date,Rents.return_date,Car.rate,Rents.rental_status From Rents INNER JOIN Client ON Rents.ID = Client.ID INNER JOIN Car ON Rents.car_id = Car.car_id";
        DB = new SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText, sql_con);
        DS.Reset();
        DB.Fill(DS);
        DT = DS.Tables[0];
        dgvRent.DataSource = DT;

        sql_con.Close();

    }
```

\loads data from database to data grid view

```
 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string txtQuery = "INSERT INTO Rents (rental_id,rental_date,return_date,rental_status) INTO Client (lName,fName) INTO Car (car_brand,car_model,plate_number,rate) VALUES ('" + txtRentID.Text + "','" + dtpStart.Text + "','" + dtpReturn.Text + "','" + cbStatus.Text + "') , ('" + cbClient.Items + "') , ('" + cbCar.Items + "')";
        ExecuteQuery(txtQuery);
        LoadData();
    }
```

\inserts data to my database
//System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'SQL logic error
near "INTO": syntax error'

Comment: Insert only has one INTO.  You need a separate Insert for each table.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?force_isolation=true&view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: The data from combo box is from different columns the same table .so how can I pass separate them into each columns in data grid view

Comment: The code is failing an INSERT into the database, not from database to grid.  You need two insert instructions to write to two database tables.